# Why PhpStorm isn't using htaccess file?

Tags: .htaccess, phpstorm, wamp

I have an `.htaccess` file for page redirecting. It works fine in wampserver, but in PhpStorm, it doesn't work and phpstorm doesn't use `.htaccess`.

For example, this works in wampserver:

```
localhost/Example/Page
```

This doesn't work in phpstorm:

```
localhost:63342/Example/Page

// 404 Not Found
```

Any thoughts on this problem?

Comment: `localhost:63342/` means that you are using **PhpStorm's own simple built-in web server** instead of your WAMP and it does NOT support mod_rewrite. Configure PhpStorm to use your web server/correct URLs .. or use them directly outside of IDE.

Answer (score 1):

.htaccess is used by the Apache webserver. It's not used by the PHPStorm web-browser though. If you want to be able to use it there, you would want to setup the 'Web path for project root' and point it to the appropriate location, as set in an Apache vhost.